# Setting Margin / Inset for cells in Tablelayout in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, tablelayout

Is there anyway to set margin for a cell in `TableLayout` (for swing application) like `Insets` in `GridBagLayout`.

I need this to space between cells in table.  One solution is that adding rows or columns that is needed space.

If The solution is applicable for netbeans, I will be more glad.

Comment: Have you considered using an `EmptyBorder`?

Comment: thanks.this is worked for jlabels :) or components that do not have borders, but components like buttons, this is not worked, additional question:do you advise using tablelayout instead of gridbaglayout in this manner ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve so it's difficult to provide advice, if you're missing a feature then maybe it's not the right solution for this case.  You could add the `JButton` (or other components) to transparent `JPanel`s or use a `CompoundBorder` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer interesting point to suggest the usage of EmptyBorders for MigLayout, TableLayout (or/same as for standard GridBagLayout/SpringLayout)

Comment: *"but components like buttons, this is not worked"*  Add them to a `JPanel` and the `EmtpyBorder` to the panel before adding it to the outer layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two `TableLayout` managers. The [Clear thoughts](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html)' `TableLayout` and the more recent [Esoteric Softwares'](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout) `TableLayout`.

I provide a simple example using both managers. We put six buttons on the window
and add some space between them.

**Clear thoughts' solution**

```
package com.zetcode;

import info.clearthought.layout.TableLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TableLayoutGaps2 extends JFrame {

    public TableLayoutGaps2() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Gaps");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


   private void initUI() {

        JPanel base = new JPanel();
        base.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)
        );

        double cols[] = {
            TableLayout.PREFERRED,
            TableLayout.PREFERRED,
            TableLayout.PREFERRED
        };

        double rows[] = {
            TableLayout.PREFERRED,
            TableLayout.PREFERRED
        };

        TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(cols, rows);
        layout.setHGap(5);
        layout.setVGap(5);

        base.setLayout(layout);

        base.add(new JButton("Button"), "0, 0");
        base.add(new JButton("Button"), "1, 0");
        base.add(new JButton("Button"), "2, 0");
        base.add(new JButton("Button"), "0, 1");
        base.add(new JButton("Button"), "1, 1");
        base.add(new JButton("Button"), "2, 1");

        add(base);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableLayoutGaps2 ex = new TableLayoutGaps2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The gaps are added using the following methods:

```
layout.setHGap(5);
layout.setVGap(5);
```

[image: Gaps]

**Esoteric softwares's solution**

```
package com.zetcode;

import com.esotericsoftware.tablelayout.swing.Table;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class TableLayoutGaps3 extends JFrame {

    public TableLayoutGaps3() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Gaps");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


   private void initUI() {

        Table table = new Table();
        getContentPane().add(table);

        table.addCell(new JButton("Button")).pad(5, 5, 2.5f, 2.5f);
        table.addCell(new JButton("Button")).pad(5, 2.5f, 2.5f, 2.5f);
        table.addCell(new JButton("Button")).pad(5, 2.5f, 2.5f, 5);
        table.row();
        table.addCell(new JButton("Button")).pad(2.5f, 5, 5, 2.5f);
        table.addCell(new JButton("Button")).pad(2.5f, 2.5f, 5, 2.5f);
        table.addCell(new JButton("Button")).pad(2.5f, 2.5f, 5, 5);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableLayoutGaps3 ex = new TableLayoutGaps3();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The gaps between the components are added with the `gap()` method.

However, I cannot recommend any of these two layout managers. Instead use
one of the following layout managers:

1. MigLayout
2. GroupLayout
3. FormLayout

They are more flexible and powerful. These managers cope way better with 
**many** challanges of the layout management.